# How do I left-align a text field for large viewports and switch to centered for smaller viewports using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, text-alignment

I have [some code](http://codeply.com/go/uqMHnq96JN) (see below) which, when running in a small viewport, should center the `img` and `h1` and drop them below the image. For some reason only the image centers though and not the `h1`.

```
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-auto text-md-left text-center">
                        <img src="http://www.joncage.co.uk/img/JonCage.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Jon Cage" class="rounded-circle">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <div class="row text-md-left text-center">
                          <h1>Jon Cage</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row text-justify">
                          <p>Jon is not very good at Bootstrap 4.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

I've crawled over the docs multiple times but I'm struggling to see why this works in one case and not in the other.

I'm probably missing something fundamental here but advice in other Q/A's on this site suggest `text-center` should apply from the smallest viewport and upwards to adding `text-md-left` should only apply to larger viewports. Even If I just try with the text-center it doesn't appear to want to center the `h1`. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.row`-s have `display: flex;` property and it means [Flexbox Layout Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) has been activated. Thus, inner elements - `<h1>` and `<p>` - have become flex items in a flex container. To align flex items inside their container as you want you might use `justify-content: center;` property on `.row` elements for small viewports in your styles instead of `text-align: center;`.

Comment: Okay, that's good; Changing the `row` containing the `h1` so that it's class is `row justify-content-center justify-content-md-start` does indeed solve the issue. One more question though; how come applying the same to the image stops _it_ centering properly?

Comment: the image isn't a flex item. in your markup it goes like this: .row->.col-md-auto text-md-left text-center->img. So, here element with .col-md-auto text-md-left text-center is a flex-item. Whereas in aforementioned cases the markup was like .row->h1 and .row->p So, h1 and p are flex items. Flex layout touches only containers and its direct children. Everything outside container and inside children remains as was.

Comment: yes, it is quite a topic. I am sure you will get it quickly.

Comment: Your suggestion that flex layout only penetrates one layer deep was the key (and not something that was made clear in any docs I'd read). I added a container and a div for the first row. With a bit of fiddling I got that working and the result is now [live](http://www.joncage.co.uk) - thanks for the help :)

Comment: Great to hear! You are welcome! :) Actually, I remember reading this information that flex layout only penetrates one layer deep somewhere on MDN...On the other hand, there are lots of articles there and they get edited constantly. So, maybe you just didn't get to the right article there :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create separate divs specifically for each viewport and display or hide them with the class names found here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

You can more easily control your content with this approach.

Comment: Seems rather wasteful to have to re-iterate content multiple times but I guess for a small page like this it wouldn't be the end of the world.